# select a dropdown box using Selenium python

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am having trouble selecting a particular dropdown element  via Selenium. The website is password protected so I have shared a snapshot of it. The attached snapshot shows what is visible when I right-click on the element and choose 'Inspect'. I am selecting XPATH which I have pasted in the pictures address bar to show what it is. Then I use the following line in my script to click it but it says element is not visible.

> [image]

```
WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, 240).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dateRangeType"]'))).click()
```

I have noticed that this element does not have a class to it. If that is the reason it is  not working, how would I select an element with id, name but no class?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself, the element was supposed to be clicked from the top of its hierarchy:

```
WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, 240).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="individual_member_det"]/div/div/div[6]/select'))).click()
```

Comment: Usually it's better to use [`Select()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) to handle such kind of drop-down menu. Also note that timeout `240` in `WebDriverWait(Chromedriver, 240)` means that your code will freeze for 4 minutes in case element not found... You might need to decrease this value